# Do I have to learn /o/ or /ɔ/ separately?

Tags: prononciation

I thought that French has only /ɔ/ sound, which is a bit more relaxed sound then /o/sound. But when I try to find the pronunciation symbols for my vocabulary book, both of the rounded vowels appear.

For example, the words 'comme' and 'alors' come with /ɔ/sound. 'Cause' in 'a cause de' appears with /o/.

Do I have to memorize these different pronunciations? Surely there must be some rules as to how to pronounce it, mustn't it?

Comment: I wouldn't worry, as most answers indicate. Moreover, the sounds can be different depending on the part of France you are, for instance in South you'll more likely hear /ɔ/ . Some examples in the second half of this page : https://francaisdenosregions.com/2017/07/06/ces-mots-qui-ne-se-prononcent-pas-de-la-meme-facon-dun-bout-a-lautre-de-la-france/ with the word 'rose', and the lack of difference in South for "sotte" VS "saute".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I wouldn't worry too much about the distinction between /ɔ/ and /o/.  In French French, /ɔ/ and /o/ tend to merge to /o/ in non-final open syllables,  contrary to varieties spoken in Belgium or Quebec.  There are only few words that are distinguished with these sounds to produce a difference in meaning.  I'm thinking right off the bat of *comme* /kɔm/ and *Côme* /kom/, *bosse* /bɔs/ and *Beauce* /bos/.  For other examples of minimal pairs, see Eauquidort's comment.  Mistaking the two or blurring them will not, I believe, impair understanding and communication much.

Now there are other sounds that need to be clearly separated in pronunciation because very often they make it possible to distinguish high-frequency words or meaningful units between each other, such as, for example /ɔ̃/, /ɑ̃/ and /ɛ̃/.  Think of *qu'on*, *con* /kɔ̃/, *quand*, *qu'en* /kɑ̃/, *qu'un* /kɛ̃/, *bon* /ɔ̃/, *banc* /bɑ̃/, *bain*, *ben* /bɛ̃/ etc.  The same would be true of /y/ and /u/ in *tout* and *tu*, *vous*, *vu*, *roue*, *rue* etc.

This is the case in English as well.  Somebody that would mistake /i:/ for /ɪ/ or have no distinction between the two, which is typical of a strong French accent, and pronounce *leave* and *live*, *fit* and *feet*, *did* and *deed*, *Pete* and *pit*, *read* and *rid* or *seat* and *sit* in the same way with French /i/ would make it harder to be understood because the opposition between /ɪ/ and /i:/ is so important in English.

Comment: Off the top of my head, other pairs are cotte and côte, conne and cône, roc and rauque, hotte and hôte, os and hausse, sole and saule, possibly phone and faune (but I say both with a closed /o/), notre and nôtre (but I say both with /ɔ/), pomme and paume, OTAN and autant, oral and aural, osier the matter and (vous) osiez. If you allow proper nouns, mode and Maude, ode and Aude, bonne and Beaune. Belgian French has fosse and fausse, pot and peau, mots and maux, boulot and bouleau to boot, but those are dialectal

Comment: Bref, I don't think there's so little pairs than that

Comment: @Eauquidort. Thanks for the other examples.  My feeling still is that /ɔ/ and /o/ are in complementary distribution in spite of the minimal pairs that we can come up with with open o /ɔ/ in closed syllables and closed o /o/ in open syllables.  If I'm completely off the mark, I'll amend the answer accordingly.  I'd be interested in your take on this.

Comment: I'm fairly sure most native speakers use /ɪ/, not /i/, for "fit", "did", "pit", "rid", and "sit". Phonetic length by itself isn't usually important in English. (And most native speakers would probably be consciously unaware of why "fit" and "feet" are still recognizably different if pronounced /fit/ and /fi:t/, respectively. :) )

Comment: @chepner  I'm using the old notation I was taught back in the days that goes back to the symbols Daniel Jones used in his English Pronouncing Dictionary, what I have in mind is the"fit" and "feet" vowel sound.  I do realize it's bit outdated now.  Feel free to change it.

Answer (score 12):

A contrast between close-mid /o/ and open-mid /ɔ/ is present in many varieties of French. But the distribution of the two sounds varies between accents. Some accents have distinctions in vowel length as well as in vowel quality, but I think that most French learners are not taught an accent with vowel length distinctions.

In some positions, the contrast is "neutralized", and you can predict with confidence that either [o] or [ɔ] will be used. For example, many speakers in France can only have [o] when the vowel sound is at the end of a word, as in *pot* and *peau* (both pronounced [po]). [But in some French-speaking regions, /ɔ/ is possible at the end of a word.](https://books.google.com/books?id=doYT4VXnhnAC&pg=PA178&lpg=PA178&dq=French%20neutralization%20o%20%C9%94)

In the north of France, either /o/ or /ɔ/ can occur before a word-final consonant sound. As LPH's answer says, many spelling patterns are associated with one sound or the other. The sound [ɔ] mainly appears in words spelled with the uncircumflexed letter o. The spellings *au, eau, ô*  tend to indicate [o], as in *saute* [sot]. A plain letter o can also be pronounced as [o]. Before a word-final [z] sound, [o] tends to be used, as in *rose* [roz].

A well-known feature of accents in the south of France is the use of [ɔ] in place of [o] in syllables ending in a consonant sound. A speaker from southern France might use [ɔ] in words like *saute* and *rose* (you can see a map on this website: "[Petit guide linguistique à l’usage des gens du Nord en vacances dans le Sud de la France](https://francaisdenosregions.com/2018/06/10/petit-guide-linguistique-pour-les-gens-du-nord-en-vacances-dans-le-sud/)", par Mathieu Avanzi, *Français de nos régions*).

Answer (score 1):

There's no rule, but there are patterns. For example, words with the same syllables *tend* to have the same pronunciation.

> école, coupole, créole, agricole, vole are all /ɔ/
>
> austral, hausse, cause, exhausser, fausse, gaussien are all /o/
>
> binôme, biome, lymphome, dôme, diplome, atome are all /o/
>
> comme, homme, consomme, dégomme, nomme, pomme, gomme are all /ɔ/

Of course there are exceptions, but if you're unsure you can try that and most of the times you won't be too far off.

However, you should pay attention to *where* the syllable is in the word, it may be important! With *-omm-* for example, it's an open "o" **only** when it's the **last** syllable. If not, it's a closed "o".

> commère, hommage, nommer, consommer are all /o/
>
> voler, abolir, absolu, cajoler, décoler, hologramme, oligarchie are all /o/

It's actually also a common pattern for a "o" syllable to be closed when it's inside the word and open when it's at the end.

Comment: Careful with that second part, the merger of /ɔ/ and /o/ in non-final syllables is mostly a French phenomenon, and is going to feel quite accented in Belgium or Quebec

Comment: @Eauquidort "merger of /ɔ/ and /o/"? What do you mean?

Comment: @Eauquidort And I always answer assuming people are learning France French, I don't think that deserves a -1. If there's a difference in other regional dialects, feel free to mention it and I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: If /ɔ/ and /o/ used to contrast in non-final open syllables, but now there's only /o/, they merged to /o/ in that environment, just some linguistics lingo. I mostly wanted to mention it because that's a part of the France French accent that's viewed rather negatively outside (mocked when imitating the accent, and so on), so it's best learners know that it's specific to it. I'm not the one who downvoted your answer though

Comment: @Eauquidort. Does this mean that "L'eau qui dort" and "Loki dort" don't sound the same in Belgian French as they do in French French ?

Answer (score 0):

You do have to do that, *learn each separately*; just as in English, you have to learn them case by case (mostly);

*English*

> - ɔ:        hall, tall, walk, thought, pause, paw, law, north, …
> - ɒ         lock, pot, sausage, Austria, …

*French*

> - ɔ        sorte, homme, comme, tonne, pomme, Paul, …
> - o        rose, pause, cause, oser, dose, …

There is a bit of regularity though ([réf.](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prononciation_du_fran%C3%A7ais#Voyelles_2));

- o          /ɔ/, /o/
- ô          /o/
- au        /o/ (very rarely /ɔ/)
- eau      /o/

The grapheme "au" has regularly the /o/ pronunciation; the /ɔ/ pronunciation is an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not worry for this phonetic difference between /ɔ/ and /o/! In fact they rely on the same supra phonemic category /O/ and are never opposed in a minimal pair. Whatever your prononciation people will understand you.

a phonetic rule : /ɔ/ can officially not occur at the end of the word (but some local exceptions exist, for example /velɔ/ for bicycle in the region of Besançon.

an orthographic rule: The theory says that when you hear /o/ inside a word it should be written [au] but in some places people do not pronounce differently the two o (for example in Grenoble).

The truly important point is to pronounce differently the French nasal vowels (i.e., [in, un, on, an] =/ɛ̃ œ̃ ɔ̃ ɑ̃/) in the words for example *pain, lundi, mon, mange* from their correspondant oral vowels *pas, /lødi/, mot, mage* or you will have some difficulties to be understood.