# Pronunciation of "commerce"

Tags: prononciation, voyelles

I have read in [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/commerce), [Word Reference](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/commerce) and in [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/commerce) that "commerce" is pronounced /kɔ.mɛʁs/. However, I hear an /o/ instead of an /ɔ/ in the corresponding audios in both WR and Wiktionary web pages. Is it just me or is this /ɔ/ not pronounced accurately as in "porte"? Maybe the difference is related to stress?

Comment: Maybe a regional pronunciation ? If I imagine "commerce" with a closed [o], that sounds to my ears like a feature from the South of France.

Comment: @Greg I expected TLFi, Word Reference and Wiktionary to point to the standard (Parisian AFAIK) French pronunciation. Don't you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I have to learn /o/ or /ɔ/ separately?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/38073/do-i-have-to-learn-o-or-%c9%94-separately)

Comment: @jiliagre I'm not asking if I have to learn the 2 phonems, I want to know what native French speakers use in this specific case. If there are regional differences, I want to know them.

Comment: Native French speakers might use both pronunciations. There are regional and individual variations. I suspect that people who say \ʁoz\ for *rose* are more likely to say \kɔ.mɛʁs\ while people who say \ʁɔzə\ are more likely to say \ko.mɛʁsə\.

Comment: I pronounce rose as in viscose and cirrhose , and commerce as commettre cor commencer.

Comment: @LaurentS. So do I but that doesn't means you and I pronounce them the same way ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In French, the pronunciation between /o/ and /ɔ/ is quite close. In the case of "commerce", it is effectively a /o/; the o is pronounced like "eau" (water) and not as "porte".

However, depending on the region, the accents differ and many pronunciations are "distorted" or at least less accentuated.

I found another recording recorded by someone of French origin (and not English like on Wiktionary), maybe that will help you to distinguish:

- commerce: https://easypronunciation.com/fr/french/word/commerce
- porte: https://easypronunciation.com/fr/french/word/porte
- eau: https://easypronunciation.com/fr/french/word/eau

Comment: It's odd that, even in the link you mentioned in which I clearly hear /ko.mɛʁs/ in the audio , the IPA transcription says /kɔ.mɛʁs/. I thought that someone would have noted and fixed that inconsistency at some point.

Comment: Indeed, according to my answer, I will use /ko.mɛʁs/ instead. Maybe I am not pronouncing it correctly myself ... As I said, the distinction between open and closed o is quite close, even lost depending on the region and the words. See: https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Annexe:Prononciation/fran%C3%A7ais#Changements_historiques if your read French.

Comment: Thanks for the useful link! As a self taught languages learner, I find very frustrating when dictionaries use outdated (aka "traditional") IPA transcriptions.

Answer (score 2):

As a French language learner, you shouldn't focus on differences no native French really cares of.

What is important is mispronunciations that would either lead to a different word than the one expected (rare) or prevent the listener to easily or at all understand what you want to say.

Using /o/ or /ɔ/ in *commerce* isn't either of these cases so just use whatever vowel you like. Nobody will notice.

Answer (score 0):

The standard pronunciation is [kɔ mεʀs] as found in the [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/commerce). Nevertheless, there are variations and [o] is also found ; this is also true for a large number of other nouns, for instance "restaurant". For example, my personal pronunciation for these two is /o/ (as internalised, not a result of practicing). Either one is acceptable. However, in "restaure" there is just one possibility and that is /ɔ/. In "restorez", again the two are possible. Apparently, there exists a pnonétic principle for deducing where the change is possible and even likely, but I am not aware of it. It could be a question having to do with the phonetic vowel that follows, whether it is a nasal or not.

Comment: Personally, I always heard that the "o" was always pronounced /ɔ/ if the vowel of the next syllabe was a silent "e". Remark that it is not the only case where the "o" os pronounced /ɔ/, but I don't know an example of such a "o" where it is pronounced /o/

Comment: @AbelMilor An example is "rose"; standard:  [ʀo:z], ie north, central; extreme southern part:  /rɔz/. Here is an interesting reference in the way of showing a little of the unsuspected variety there is in the pronunciation of French:  https://www.buzzfeed.com/fr/julesdarmanin/grace-aux-cartes-de-ce-linguiste-on-sait-qui-prononce-rose